# Как передать данные между несколькими activity?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-intent

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите как передать данные между активностями. Делаю переход на MainActivity и передаю данные. Но данные мне нужно получить не на MainActivity, а на другой.

```
public void doSomething(Void result) {
      //Переход делаю на MainActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
     // Данные нужно получить на другой активности не MainActivity
        intent.putExtra("json", dj.getmString());
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
```

После чего перехожу на MainActivity а с нее на другую activity(tooActivity). На 
tooActivity пытаюсь получить данные:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        if(intent !=null) {
            String mString = intent.getExtras().getString("json");
            System.out.print(mString);
        }
```

Но все время выпадает ошибка:

```
TAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.ferisov.ziam, PID: 2745
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ferisov.ziam/com.ferisov.ziam.SelliPhone}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ищите данные там где вы их передали

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
if(intent !=null) {
    String mString = intent.getStringExtra("json", "");
    System.out.print(mString);
}
```

Comment: Да я просто думал может есть какой то способ передавать данные на любую activity. Но походу нет.

Comment: @АнатолийФерисов, способа из коробки нет т.к. он не нужен. Но вы можете создать базовую абстрактную актвити и переопределить там метод `startActivity()`, передавать в него данные из Intent текущей и присваивать эти данные новому Intent. Так у вас все актвити будут получать одинаковые данные при минимуме кода. Но это ещё вопрос стоит ли такое городить